# Get changed element of array in Angular

Tags: angular, angular5

I've got this component:

```
    export class RequestedProductList implements DoCheck {

        @Input() requests: Request[] = [];
        differ: any;
     constructor(
            private globalVariablesService: GlobalVariablesService,
            private route: ActivatedRoute,
            private requestService: RequestService,
            private loaderService: LoaderService,
            private collectionService: CollectionService,
            private accountService: AccountService,
            private differs: IterableDiffers
        ) {
            this.requests = requestService.requests;
            this.differ = differs.find([]).create(null);

            this.route.params.subscribe(
                params => this.accountId = params["id"]
            );

            this.loadRequests();
            this.loadAccountData();        
        }

ngDoCheck() {
        const change = this.differ.diff(this.requests);
        console.log(change);
    }
```

The requests array is shown in a template and has some bidirectional bound form fields like this.

```
<td><input class="form-control form-control-sm comment" [(ngModel)]="request.comment" type="text" placeholder=".form-control-sm"></td>
```

When I enter data is this form fields the ngDoCheck() runs but change is always null.

I'm trying to get the object that is changed that was in the the array so I can update this in the database. Why is the differ not detecting the change?